# Advanced statistics in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, statistics

I have a slight problem. I have a dataset, which contains values measured by a weather station, which I want to analyze further using MySQL database and PHP.
Basically, the first column of the db contains the date and the other columns temperature, humidity, pressure etc.
Now, the problem is, that for the calculation of the mean, st.dev., max, min etc. it is quite simple. However there are no build-in commands for other parameters which I need, such as kurtosis etc.

What I need is for example to calculate the skewness, mean, stdev etc. for the individual months, then days etc.
For the build-in functions it is easy, for example finding some of the parameters for the individual months would be:

```
SELECT AVG(Temp), STD(Temp), MAX(Temp)
FROM database
GROUP BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)
```

Obviously I cannot use this for the more advanced parameters. I thought about ways of achieving this and I could only think of one solution. I manually wrote a function, which processes the values and calculates the things such as kurtosis using the particular formulae. But, what that means is that I would need to create arrays of data for each month, day, etc. depending on what I am currently calculating. So for example, i would first need to take the data and split it into arrays lets say Jan11, Feb11, Mar11...... and each array would contain the data for that month. Then I would apply the function on those arrays and create new variables with the result (lets say kurtosis_jan11, kurtosis_feb11 etc.)

Now to my question. I need help with the splitting of data. The problem is that I dont know in advance which month the data starts and which it ends, so I cannot set fixed variables for this. The program first has to check the first month and then create new array for each month, day etc. until it reaches the last record. And for each it would create the array.

That of course would be maybe one solution but if anyone has any other ideas about how to go around this problem I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: use having(in sql) to check for specific month

Comment: well the problem is that I do not know in advance how many months there are, I need an array for each month in more than one year, so it is not just all data from january, all data from febrauray etc. - then it would surely be possible to create 12 arrays and then fill them up using Having.

Comment: Date have a range like from january to march or its sparsed like january,april,december?

Comment: the dates are in regular 5-minute intervals, but they start for example in Mar 2011 and go through to Apr 2013 etc. So in this case I would need about 25 arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can do more complex queries to achieve this. Here are some examples http://users.drew.edu/skass/sql/ , including Skew

Comment: this seems quite useful, unfortunately Im just a beginner in SQL and don't really know how to implement this... could you maybe give me an example, lets say I have the dates in the Date variable (see my example in the question) and then I have the temperature saved in the Temp column and I want to perform a particular function x() on the data,´grouped by month

Comment: I think the key is to use subqueries to get information on different data subsets. Let's say you want the average difference for each month:  SELECT (SELECT AVG(d1.Temp) FROM database d1)-AVG(d2.Temp),YEAR(d2.Date),MONTH(d2.Date) FROM database d2 GROUP BY YEAR(d2.Date),MONTH(d2.Date) you can use the same table multiple times and combine its results as they were different tables

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> SELECT AVG(Temp), STD(Temp), MAX(Temp)
> FROM database
> GROUP BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)
> ```
>
> having date between date_from and date_to

I think you want a group of data in between a data range.

Comment: but then I would have to set this for each individual month, and even then it would not be possible, because I do not know how many months there are - this is variable in the databases, the program needs to check this and create new array for each month of each year

Comment: do you know the start date and the end date of that query?

Comment: no, they vary because new data is added to the database every 5 min

Comment: so you dont know date1 and date2 of "having date between date1 and date2"? Can you use count() to count how many rows are inserted?

Comment: I think thats what I will have to do, loop through the whole dataset and create array each time the month does not match the month of the previous record.

Comment: yes thats what you should do if you dont know the parameters or its dynamic.